# Downloading only new files in GoodData

Tags: gooddata

How can I use the `"Download File"` component to only download new files or files that have been **updated** remotely?

---

Consider a graph like the following:

[image]

where `File Download` is defined as:

[image]

I have many *.csv files in `${S3_OR_DATA_DIR_LOCATION}`; I'm adding one every day).

How can I make sure GoodData only downloads **new** files AND files that have been updated? Would making the option `"Overwrite existing files"` `False` do it? Or would that only download new files and not update existing files that have been updated?

Answer (score 1):

The **File Download** CloudConnect component by itself does not support action as downloading only a new file(s), which appeared in the source folder as it does not have any previous state remembering mechanism implemented, but as it has input port, it is possible to implement such mechanism yourself with using of **File List** CloudConnect component with a little help of Reformat, some Joiner and CSV Writer CloudConnect components. This way you can determine the content of the source folder and write it there in a plain text file. The mechanism can be designed the way, that the next processing would read the state file from the previous run and determine, what a new files are and then sends a list of a new files to the **File Download CloudConnect component’s input port**.

The another way how to process only a new files, which is way simpler then the process described in the previous article and therefore commonly used, is based on **taking advantage of folder structures in the source folder**, where there would be a dedicated folder for a new files and another dedicated folder for already processed files. The CloudConnect ETL process itself would then read a new files from its dedicated source folder and the last stage of the ETL process would contain **File Copy/Move** CloudConnect component used for transferring of the already processed new files from its dedicated folder to folder containing all already processed files.